# Charge moving in an electric field and magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrical-engineering

lets say I have an electron moving towards an oppositely charged plate.
Perpendicular to the electrical force vector, exists a magnetic field.
How would I calculate the force on the electron?
Like such?

$$F=qE+q(\int \frac{qE}{m}dt\times B)$$
acceleration of a charge in an electric field is equal to the following.
$$a=\frac{qE}{m}$$
and thus, the time integral is equal to velocity.

Comment: You should be simply applying the Lorentz force law. What you are writing makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be assuming that $\vec{v} = \int \frac{q}{m} \vec{E} \, dt$ and then plugging this into the Lorentz force law.  But this isn't valid unless $\vec{F} = q \vec{E}$, i.e., there is no magnetic field.

Instead, you need to view the Lorentz force law as a differential equation, and solve it:
$$
m \frac{d\vec{v}}{dt} = q \left( \vec{E} + \vec{v} \times \vec{B} \right)
$$
Write out the components of this equation in terms of $v_x$, $v_y$, and $v_z$.  Then solve the resulting coupled ODEs to get the trajectory.